# Install Wireshark without confirm

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo, wireshark

When I tried to install Wireshark automatically with :  `sudo apt-get install -y wireshark` Ubuntu gave me that image:

[image]

How can I install wireshark from terminal without press "YES" ?why does `-y` didn't skip on that screen?

Comment: Welcome! `-y` refers to *apt* installation, the windows you show is the wireshark *configuration* of the package.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I want that auto confirm, to install `Wireshark` automatically

Comment: curious... you only need to do it once though surely...

Answer (score 3):

Here [you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413011/413144) go!

First, configure the `debconf` database:

```
echo "wireshark-common wireshark-common/install-setuid boolean true" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Then, install Wireshark:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install wireshark
```

You might also want to suppress the output of apt-get. In that case:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install wireshark > /dev/null
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you're installing in a Docker container. In my case, the tshark package has a dependency in wireshark

Comment: It's irrelevant 'why'. The question was 'how'! And some of us are facing situations where neither screen nor keyboard is accessible when installing stuff - on daily basis.
Thanks for the answer!